# Teamviewer mouse wont open the laucher

Tags: unity, launcher, mouse, remote-desktop, teamviewer

I have an issue on which I am unsure of the root cause, as in whether it is an Ubuntu issue or a TeamViewer issue.

On my computer I have the launcher set to auto-hide. When connected to it from a windows computer or an android phone or tablet, the mouse is unable to open/bring up the launcher. Pretty much every other thing seems to work except the launcher behavior.

Is this a bug in TeamViewer or in Ubuntu and how may I get rid of this issue?

Comment: Try using TightVNC. If the problem still persists it's a launcher issue. If that solves, it's a teamviewer issue

Answer (score 1):

I experienced this problem, too.

The obvious solution would be to disabled "auto hide". You could try to display the dash by pressing the super key (Windows key) which should show the launcher symbols, too.

The last workaround could be using TeamViewer in fullscreen mode and pointing the mouse to the left. This way you would not leave the TeamViewer window and the remote system recognizes this movement.